# File executable by all, yet still cannot be executed?

Tags: permissions, mount, executable

As shown by the following code:

```
ll
total 136
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kaiyin kaiyin  19067 May  9  2013 dbmeister.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kaiyin kaiyin   1617 Jul 29  2011 locuszoom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kaiyin kaiyin 112546 May  9  2013 locuszoom.R


./locuszoom
-bash: ./locuszoom: Permission denied
```

`locuszoom` is executable globally, but still can't be executed. The files are on a harddisk mounted at `/media/data1`.

Comment: Try `mount | grep '/media/data1'`. It may be that your hard disk is mounted with the `noexec` option.

Comment: Try also `strace ./locuszoom` and `file locuszoom` to identify some potential problems within your host architecture and the nature of the executable binary document. That is, an architecture mismatch x86 v. amd64 or other problem like this.

Comment: @JosephR. Indeed, it has been mounted with noexec, how do I change that into exec?

Comment: @qed See [Timo's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109138/26909).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The harddisk needs to be remounted so that `exec` mount option is included.

*excerpt from mount man page*

```
FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS
    ....
    exec   Permit execution of binaries.
```

You can do this 1 of 2 ways.

#### Examples

Via the command line.

```
$ mount -o remount,exec /media/data1
```

Or in your `/etc/fstab`.

```
# <file system>      <dir>         <type>    <options>             <dump> <pass>
/dev/sdb1            /media/data1  ext4      rw,exec,noauto        0      0
```

Comment: I ended up adding the exec option into fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `locuszoom` is a shell script of some kind, it's possible bash is telling you something at the start of the script failed, rather than you can't run the script.  Try `bash -x ./locuszoom` and see if it is failing somewhere (assuming `locuszoom` is a bash shell script).